# Sendmail still displays through telnet even though I'm using Postfix

Tags: debian, postfix, sendmail, telnet

I recently installed and configured Postfix, and removed every aspect of Sendmail that I could from my Debian x86 system.

```
telnet localhost 25
```

...still returns that I'm using Sendmail. I've uninstalled it, stopped it multiple times, and started/restarted Postfix multiple times as well.

Comment: Exactly what did you do?

Comment: Postfix will answer on port 25 as well as sendmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the output of:

```
 netstat -anp | grep :25
```

Comment: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      750/sendmail: MTA:` is the output I get. I also seem to not be able to stop the process from running, as /etc/init.d/sendmail stop doesn't give me any error when i continually type it. It's not on my startup list, either.

Comment: you still have sendmail running - you can do a 'ps -eaf | grep sendmail' to look at it - kill it, also you can try a 'whereis sendmail' and rename or remove it.